# How to save/export a Word file (.docx) as a single HTML page?

Tags: html, microsoft-word-2016

I am using Word 2016.

I want to save (export) a Word (.docx) document as a *single* HTML page. How can I do this

Comment: Does `Save As` and selecting "Single File Web Page (*.mht, *.mhtml)" do want you need?